# Showing empty result of non-object value when parsing data in Javascript

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.8

I'm using Laravel with Sweetalert and I tried to show a custom popup message which is showing a value of Laravel variable:

```
      $(document).on('click', '#custombtn', function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            let form = $(this).parents('form');
            swal(
                {
                    title: "Alert!",
                    text: "Youre wallet balance is: {!! digits2persian(json_decode($user_wallet->balance)) !!}",
                    type: "warning",
                    allowEscapeKey: false,
                    allowOutsideClick: false,
                    showCancelButton: true,
                    confirmButtonColor: "#DD6B55",
                    confirmButtonText: "Yes",
                    cancelButtonText: "No",
                    showLoaderOnConfirm: true,
                    closeOnConfirm: false
                }).then((isConfirm) => {
                if (isConfirm.value === true) {
                    window.location.href = {!! json_encode(route('courseRegistrationWithWallet', ['course'=>$item->cor_id,'wallet'=>$user_wallet->id ?? ''])) !!}
                }
                return false;
            });
        });
```

But now the problem is, when `$user_wallet->balance` is returning *null*, this error will occurs:

**Trying to get property 'balance' of non-object**

So I tried this to show *empty* result, if the variable is not set:

```
{!! digits2persian(json_decode($user_wallet->balance)) ?? '' !!}
```

But didn't solve this problem and the error still appears!

So how to fix this issue?

Comment: YOu can modify your conditional statement to 
```{!! $user_wallet->balance ? digits2persian(json_decode($user_wallet->balance)) : '' !!}```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read the error message carefully:

> Trying to get property 'balance' of non-object

It is not the *balance* which is null, but the thing *containing* the balance. So you need to handle **$user_wallet** being null, e.g.:

```
isset($user_wallet) ? digits2persian(json_decode($user_wallet->balance)) : 'No wallet'
```

Answer (score 0):

try this `if($user_wallet->balance > 0){}`

or this `$user_wallet->balance ?? "0"`